# Why does the opencart .gitignore file include the modification folder?

Tags: git, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

opencart 2.2.0.0 and 2.3.0.2

.gitignore

```
...  
# Modification Files
/upload/system/storage/modification/*
!/upload/system/storage/modification/index.html
...
```

I can understand other rules.
cache: can be regenerated anytime.
vendor: can be downloaded by composer.

But if we install some extension, which is located inside system/storage/modification, as part of the project.

We did not commit modification files to git. Later, we have a project needs to use this version.

We clone the project, we fetch, we pull, and find out that something we need are missing. And it seems that we don't have other way to get the modification files.

How do we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone gave me an answer, it seems more reasonable.
Modification files is like cache, can be regenerated if we go to backend > extend.

Answer (score 0):

This `.gitignore` is really designed for people who are contributing to the [OpenCart project on Github](https://github.com/opencart/opencart).  If you are not contributing to the project, go ahead and modify it per your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

from https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?p=680475#p680475 explains:

Post by daveyoi:

> Files in the modification directory are generated files. Every time
>   you run modification refresh the files are deleted and regenerated.
>
> They should not be in your code control. You should commit the module
>   files to code control including the ocmod xml that then generates the
>   modification files not the resulting modification files themselves.

Comment: I recommend that you wrap the quote in quote formatting to make it obvious that the text was quoted from another source.